# Let $K$ be a field. Show that $K[t]$ is finitely generated as a $K[t^2,t^3]$-module and find a generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Using the variables $t^2,t^3$ I think that $K[t^2,t^3]$ contains all polynomials of $K[t]$ except those of degree $1$ since $t$ cannot be made from products of $t^2,t^3$ so I think that the module is generated by the set $\{1,t\}$ since given any $f(t)=a_nt^n+...+a_1t+a_0\in K[t]$ we can write this as $(a_nt^n+...+a_2t^2+a_0)(1)+a_1(t)$ where $a_nt^n+...+a_2t^2+a_o$ and $a_1$ are in $K[t^2,t^3]$.Is this correct and how I can I write it more rigorously? Do I need to use the fact that $K$ is a field and hence $K[t]$ is a PID?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by making a linear term?  Don't I need to show, for example, how $3t+1$ can be generated? Is that not generated by $\{1,t\}$?

Comment: $K[t^2,t^3] = K+t^2 K[t]$ so $K[t] = K[t^2,t^3]+tK$

Comment: So what I’ve written is correct isn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $K[t]$ as a $K[t^2, t^3]$-module can be generated by the two elements $1$ and $t$, just as you say.